# Why is this hide show function not working?

Tags: javascript, toggle

I am a javascript beginner, but I have implemented this code elsewhere and it worked. Did I overlook something obvious?

https://jsfiddle.net/x3oj787q/1/

html:

```
<a href="javascript:toggle_visibility('div');">help</a>

<div id="div"style="display: none;">
help
</div>
```

js:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
      e.style.display = 'none';
   else
      e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: Please add your code... Also, man, people are fast with the downvotes.

Comment: thanks, im new to stack overflow and still trying to figure it all out

Comment: Load type: No wrap. https://jsfiddle.net/x3oj787q/2/

Comment: thanks, it works, but i am having a hard time seeing what changed

edit: i see now, thanks again

Comment: FWIW, consider using a button instead: that's what they're for.
`<button type="button" onclick="toggle_visibility('div')">HELP</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is perfect, but you are creating your function in the onLoad of the page which means its out of scope when you call it from your a href tag.  If you compare your Fiddle with @dtsq, you'll notice if you click the JAVASCRIPT button that the Load Type is `onLoad` for yours, and `No wrap - in <body>` for his.

`No wrap - in <body>` tells the browser to not wrap your js code and to place it in the body. 
 Notice that `No wrap - in <head>` would work just fine as well.

`onLoad` tells the browser to wrap the code so it will run in the onLoad window event.  You said you implemented this code elsewhere and it worked.  When you add this plain javascript code to the head or body section, it works fine.  But I'm willing to bet you're trying to place this code in a JQuery block or other onLoad area which causes the issue due to scope.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Still don't know what you mean.

Comment: I mean care to explain because _Your code is perfect, but you are loading it in the onLoad of the page_ don't mean anything.

Comment: Ok.  I updated the answer to be a little more specific on why creating it in the onLoad is causing the issue.